# How to create List or Array, of an <ul>/<li> tags on a web page ?( RobotFramework, Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ui-automation

Here is a example, I have 24 Elements with this CSS Selector **".main-column>div>ul>li>a"** and i want to check all links and text of this tags.

Basically i am try to do Loop over it but i am not sure how to do it with Robot Framework.

```
${all_elements} css=.main-column>div>ul>li>a
```

I have tried with

```
 : FOR ${a} IN RANGE ${all_element} 
\ Get Text ${all_element}
```

Please advice me how to do it, or a better approach for it. is it possible to convert **${all_element}** to array. So we can loop over it, and try to get all links and text? Please advice

Comment: Have you considered using [Get web elements](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20WebElements)?

Comment: Tried with that also but getting following Error
I have tried with, but getting following error
**User keyword 'verify_all_sub_elements' contains no keywords.**
`@{Elements}=    Get WebElements    ${all_element}
    :FOR  ${EachElement} in @{Elements}
    \@{text}=   Get Text  ${EachElement}
    \Log to Console    @{text}`

Answer (score 6):

Try this , if it helps:

```
Sample Test
@{Elements}=    Get WebElements    ${AllElements}
:FOR    ${EachElement}    in    @{Elements}  
\    Get Text    ${EachElement}
```

Comment: Good answer. Some textual context with respect to the code block could have been helpful to the future readers.

Comment: Thank you, DebanjanB,  Will add the textual content

Comment: I have tried with, but getting following error
**User keyword 'verify_all_sub_elements' contains no keywords.**
`@{Elements}=    Get WebElements    ${all_element}
    :FOR  ${EachElement} in @{Elements}
    \@{text}=   Get Text  ${EachElement}
    \Log to Console    @{text}`

Comment: @ashacr any thoughts ?

Comment: Screenshot of code :- 
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZyTf.png

Comment: @GurinderSingh add `*** testcase ***` before starting test cases

Comment: @Gurinder ,

Maybe you are not escaping indented cells, I see that the back slash spacing or the indentation issue.

There need to  be a tab or 4 times space between \ and then the starting of the keyword
    1. After a statement with 'FOR' each line, that relates to the loop should start with \ (backslash)
    2. After the backslash you need  to give atleast 2 spaces! 

For more details on FOR loop usage, the below reading might help...its quite explanatory.... 
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/05/robot-framework-tutorial-loops-conditional-execution-and-more/

Lets try and see!